# Fix this apparmor rule?

Tags: firefox, apparmor

I don't really know how to add this rule to the profile, since the name was "wired", it's not some absolute path on my system,

> kernel: type=1400 audit(1353749970.556:556): apparmor="ALLOWED"
>   operation="open" parent=1
>   profile="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}"
>   name=2F4170706C69636174696F6E2F7468656D65732F4C696F6E2D7468656D652D72656C6F61646564202F67746B2D322E302F67746B7263
>   pid=14778 comm="firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000
>   ouid=1000

Anyone know what sort of rules should I add to firefox's profile? With this unknown stuff denied from reading, firefox looks ugly (no gtk themes applied)

Comment: Just in case, that hex string is `/Application/themes/Lion-theme-reloaded /gtk-2.0/gtkrc`. Yes, with the space in the middle. No idea why it was written that way or why it's there.

Comment: @Gilles that was a mistake to have a space at the end of it, probably it was there before the author packed the theme ... anyway, the problem got solved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is encoded because it contains special chars,

Decoded the string with `aa-decode 2F4170706C69636174696F6E2F7468656D65732F4C696F6E2D7468656D652D72656C6F61646564202F67746B2D322E302F67746B7263` and found out the issue was caused by a newly introduced GTK theme.

Now it's fixed, just simple add a line to that profile, i.e `/Application/themes/** r,`

Comment: Just curious but what is the advantage of keeping themes in `/Application` and not in `~/.themes` or `/usr/share/themes`?

Comment: @vasa1 just some old partition scheme ... I don't even remember why I did that

Comment: @vasa1 I just remember the reason. I run both Ubuntu and Arch .. themes need to be shared through a common disk partition